# 502 Bad gateway error on trying to run sonarqube 127.0.0.1:9000

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, sonarqube, ubuntu-18.04

I have followed the instructions to install sonarqube on my Ubuntu 18.04 using these instructions,
https://developerinsider.co/install-sonarqube-on-ubuntu/

can someone help me out?

running `systemctl status sonar` seems to be working.

```
    ● sonar.service - SonarQube service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/sonar.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-02-14 19:38:23 PST; 38min ago
  Process: 30487 ExecStop=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.3/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 30532 ExecStart=/opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.3/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30578 (wrapper)
    Tasks: 47 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sonar.service
           ├─30578 /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.3/bin/linux-x86-64/./wrapper /opt/sonarqube/sonarqube-7.3/bin/linux-x86-64/../../
           ├─30580 java -Dsonar.wrapped=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms8m -Xmx32m -Djava.library.path=./lib -classpath ../..
           └─31259 /usr/lib/jvm/zre-8-amd64/bin/java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSI
```

but when I try `curl 127.0.0.1:9000`
this is what I get,

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check sonarqube logs and debug the error https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/troubleshooting/#:~:text=Checking%20the%20logs,-If%20you're&text=You'll%20find%20them%20in,Log%20for%20the%20main%20process.

Comment: This configuration is wrong. Note that the error message shows that it was generated by nginx, which is listening on port 9000, instead of SonarQube. You need to be running nginx on a different port than SonarQube (80 perhaps).